# Chrome API (google speech synthesis) alert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert, speech-synthesis

I am trying to use chrome.tts (Google Speech Synthesis Chrome API) for my website and I'm using javascript to build it. However, I have a problem that my 'speaking function' does not work propely without 'alert' function which I don't need.

Here's the code:

```
function speak_q(q, number) {

var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = q;
msg.volume = volume;
msg.pitch = pitch;
msg.rate = rate;
var num = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
num.text = number + "번";
num.volume = volume;
num.pitch = pitch;
num.rate = rate;

var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();


alert("OK"); // this is the one that has problem


msg.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function (voice) {
    return voice.name == "Google 한국의";
})[0];

num.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function (voice) {
    return voice.name == "Google 한국의";
})[0];

window.speechSynthesis.speak(num);

setTimeout(function () {}, 3000);

window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

When I delete the alert part I hear the awkward Korean voice and when I do not delete this I get the proper native Korean language. How can I earse this and make it work propely?

Comment: You do realize that execution will not stop at `setTimeout(function () {}, 3000);`?

Comment: It seems the question itself has nothing related with `chrome.tts`? Just `Web Speech API`.

Comment: @Xan Oh, I didn't know that. But If I delete setTimeout(function () {}, 3000);, I still get the same problem.